# How do i create an active listbox in Excel that both reflects and controls a table?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

From a sheet ("dashboard") in Excel I have a button that allow me to look up arbitrary lengths of historical stock-prices, that I can add to a list in another sheet ("List").

When I click a "add to list" button, I have written VBA code that copies the stock name and price from the "dashboard" sheet and pastes it in the next empty column in the other sheet ("List") (such that the next stock added to the list appears to the right of the previous one).

From the "dashboard" sheet, the user can perform all these actions. However, I'd like to display a list on the dashboard sheet of the stock names that the user has already added to the list, so they don't have to switch between sheets to verify what they have in the list.

I have tried several methods using a ListBox, but it always seem to be doing something strage..

Some of the code i provide below is pseudo, especialy the If statement.
This is what I have got so far:

```
Sub ListBox()

'Finding the last column number in the "List" Sheet
    LastCol = Sheets("List").Cells(9, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Same for Last Row
    LastRow = Sheets("List").Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
```

```
' Selecting the "Dashboard" sheet where my ListBox appears 
Sheets("Dashboard").Select

' Setting the ListBox equal to all cells that contain stock names 
ListBox = Sheets("List").Range(Cells(9, 2), Cells(9, LastCol)
```

And then I would like to controll the accual list in the "list" sheet from the ListBox. Something like this:

```
If Delete item in ListBox Then
Delete.Sheets("List").Range("THE COLUMN THAT CONTAINS THE ITEM DELETED FROM ListBox" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Else

End Sub
```

I appreciate any help or ideas!

Comment: This is only my guess on what your want :  on sheet dashboard, create an ActiveX ListBox with name ListBox1 ... then in the dashboard sheet module, have this code : `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` ... next line `With Sheets("List"): ListBox1.Clear: ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(9, 2), .Cells(9, 6)))): End With` ---> this line will populate ListBox1 with each value from cell B9 to F9 of sheet List. Next line `end sub`

Comment: The macro run when sheet dashboard is activated. Change `.cells(9,6)` into `.cells(9,LastCol)` if you have the LastCol variable with it's value. `With Sheets("List"): LC = .Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column: ListBox1.Clear: ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(9, 2), .Cells(9, LC)))): End With`

Comment: To delete entire column where row 9 nth column value is clicked in the ListBox :`Private Sub ListBox1_Click()` ... next line `With Sheets("List"): .Cells.Find(ListBox1.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).EntireColumn.Delete: LC = .Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column: ListBox1.Clear: For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(9, 2), .Cells(9, LC)): ListBox1.AddItem cell.Value: Next: End With` ... next line `end sub`. FYI, the macro assumed that the value in row 9 column 2 to LastCol is unique and nowhere else found in other cells of sheet List.

Comment: Thanks! The first one you provided worked perfectly. I couldn't figure out the second, so I set a column length of 150 instead of the last column. The third code worked fine, although the ListBox is still a little buggy when deleting specific assets (e.g., every now and then, a slider appears on the right side of the ListBox, The first column) Thank you alot!

Comment: For the code with LC, step run the code, and see in the Locals window if LC value gives you a correct result. For example, if in the sheet list, the last data column of row 9 is column G, then the LC result you see in the Locals window should be 7. If you hardcoded to 150 insted of LC and there is a blank cell after the last data in the nth column of row 9, your ListBox will populate with the blank cell too. If the last data of row 9 is more than 150, then your ListBox item is lack some of the data.

Comment: If you don't want a scroll-bar on the right of the LB at all, try to add `ListBox1.Height = ((LC - 1) / 2) * 30` (before the End Sub ) ---> this will make the height of the LB is 15 for each item. Play around with "30" according to your need. Please see the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim rg As Range

With Sheets("List")
    Set rg = .Range(.Cells(9, 2), .Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With

    With ListBox1
        .Clear
        .List = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rg))
        .Height = (Application.CountA(rg) / 2) * 30
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Dim rg As Range

With Sheets("List")
    .Cells.Find(ListBox1.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).EntireColumn.Delete
    Set rg = .Range(.Cells(9, 2), .Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With

    With ListBox1
        .Clear
        For Each cell In rg: .AddItem cell.Value: Next
        .Height = (Application.CountA(rg) / 2) * 30
    End With

End Sub
```

Instead using the LastColumn number, the macro above use the range of data in row 9 from column 2 to the last column of sheet List ---> variable rg.

Then it populate the LB and adjust the height of the LB according to how many item are there inside the rg.

When the LB item is clicked, it find the clicked value in sheet List, and then delete the whole column of the found cell. Then it set the rg, populate the LB and adjust LB's height.

Please note that if the data in sheet List is only one value which is in cell B9 (the cells to the right are all blank), the sub workbook_activate will throw you an error.

So if there is a possibility that there will be only one item in the LB (means the data in sheet list is only in cell B9), then just use the populating LB code from the ListBox1_click.

Comment: Thank you so much. This code is far superior. The only problem I'm having is that after I remove everything from the list (by clicking on them in the LB), a last value appears in the LB. That value is the one in cell A9 on the "List" sheet (This is where I store the dates). So when I click on (remove) the last value the LB (Date), it completely shrinks the LB, such that when I try to add new items it produces an error (Like you said it would). I tried using the populating LB code from the ListBox1_click, but it only then populated blank cells. But thank you so much! This helped alot!